# need help to fix this issue

Tags: python, mysql-python

I tried to insert data to the database using python but I got a MySQLdb error

```
self.cur.execute('''
            INSERT INTO book(book_name, book_desc, book_code, book_category, book_author, book_publisher, book_price)
            VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        ''', (book_title, book_desc, book_code, book_category, book_author, book_publisher, book_price, ))

self.db.commit()
```

I got this error:

> MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'book_code' at row 1")

Comment: What value do you have for `book_code`?

Comment: i didn't get you. you are asking for which value??

Comment: You are attempting to insert the `book_code` variable to the `book_code` column which causes this error. I'm asking what value you're using there.

Comment: book_code like 001,002 etc. i use INT datatype for book_code

Answer (score 0):

According to the values you shared in the comments, `book_code` is a string, which is incompatible with the `int` value in the database. You could overcome this issue by converting it to an `int`:

```
self.cur.execute('''
            INSERT INTO book(book_name, book_desc, book_code, book_category, book_author, book_publisher, book_price)
            VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        ''', (book_title, book_desc, int(book_code), book_category, book_author, book_publisher, book_price, ))
```